# Issue with gcloud-node using BigQuery

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

I am trying the basic example on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) to connect to BigQuery. I did `npm install --save gcloud` as advised and it seemed to have installed correctly. Is there anything else I need to install?

==============================================================

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');

// Authenticating on a per-API-basis. You don't need to do this if you auth on a
// global basis (see Authentication section above).
var bigquery = gcloud.bigquery({
  projectId: 'XXXXXX MASKED XXXXXXXXXXX',
  keyFilename: './XXXXX MASKED XXXXXXX.json'
});

// Access an existing dataset.
var schoolsDataset = bigquery.dataset('mydataset.mytable');

// Import data into a dataset.
schoolsDataset.import('./myfile', function(err, job) {});

// Get results from a query job.
var job = bigquery.job('job-id');
```

====================================================================

```
TypeError: schoolsDataset.import is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\projects\stock_quotes\app.js:15:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the docs! Sent a PR: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/pull/1067

You import data into a table, not a dataset. So one line was missing, where you access a table:

```
var schoolsTable = schoolsDataset.table('table-id');
```